# Is there a similar count method in SQL like mysql_num_row

Tags: sql, database, count

I am using SQL and I would like to count the number of rows without a loop. I can't seem to get the "COUNT" keyword working but I know that in MySQL mysql_num_row does the trick. Is there a similar method to mysql_num_row in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename
```

This will count the number of rows/entries in the table "tablename"

For more info, check out the manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

**[EDIT] As Ken White suggested you can of course narrow down the resulting recordset by adding a WHERE-clause**

Comment: +1. Just as an addition, you can qualify with a WHERE clause also: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE SomeCondition`

Answer (score 2):

Given ANY query

```
select ..
from .. multiple ..
where .. group by.. order by..
limit ..
```

Wrap it in a subquery, and COUNT(*) over it

```
select count(*) from (

select ..
from .. multiple ..
where .. group by.. order by..
limit ..

) X
```

The `) X` bit is to give it an alias name, as required by syntax.  Of course, if your original query ended with a `;`, drop it from the subquery.

Comment: Ummm... Why would you want to make a single query a pair of queries, when you can just do the filtering in the count() query itself? Try both, and look at the plan for them. (Not down-voting, because it's technically correct, but it's not a good idea IMO.)

Comment: @Ken - this is a general approach. Consider a complex query starting with `SELECT a, b, sum(c), min(D) .... group by a,b` - here do you put the `COUNT(*)`?  FYI in PHP, mysql_num_rows works on any query, hence a generalized answer to match.

Comment: @Ken: Some queries may not be easily changed so the counting is done on the query itself. I guess if they are pretty complex with subqueries as fields or with DISTINCT. I'm sure Richard can supply an example.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your reasoning; I'm not MySQL/PHP qualified ;). I probably would add that as part of the answer. @ypercube: Agreed. Both of you: I didn't see the need for adding the complexity based on the question asked. :)